# How to replace ',)' with ')'

Tags: java

How to replace ',)' with ')' I  gave replaceAll(",)",")") but i was getting an error that Unmatched closing ')' near index 0. Please let me know if there is some solution to replace this.

Answer (score 6):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) uses regular expressions, and bracket have a particular meaning in regular expressions. Just use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead, which doesn't use regex:

```
text = text.replace(",)", ")");
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how we can answer this with lambda expression in Java?

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` is expecting a regex, meaning you need to escape the parentheses yourself. Try this:

```
str.replaceAll(",\\)",")")
```

You should probably use Jon Skeet's solution, though.

Comment: Why bother escaping in the regex, when you can just use `replace` and avoid the regex to start with?

Comment: I upvoted your answer since it makes more sense. Just added for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace insted of replaceAll. Read API.

```
String input = "ab(,cd(,";  
System.out.println(input.replace("(,", "("));
```